# Will_paginate for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, pagination

I was run across issue to paging my list object in asp.net mvc where my object is simply load by LINQ-to-SQL.

Is it some kinds of will_paginates command?

in rails, i can do like

```
Users.paginate(:all, :page => 1, :page_size => 20)
```

Comment: +1 for all of you guys. Thank you. I will most simple one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out - http://pagedlist.codeplex.com/

Will create an extension method ToPagedList which can be used like so:

```
 using PagedList;

 var firstPage = list.ToPagedList(0, 20); // first page, page size = 20

 Console.WriteLine("Is first page? {0}", firstPage.IsFirstPage); // true
 Console.WriteLine("Is last page? {0}", firstPage.IsLastPage); // false
 Console.WriteLine("First value on page? {0}", firstPage[0]); // 1
 Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: I'm astonished that they've managed to make a 168k (zipped) mountain out of this molehill!

Comment: Before you criticize, you should consider that your proposed solution will perform poorly on the first (and thus most commonly requested) page (see http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/06/10/38313/), offers no pagination (paging button) features in the view, and must be re-implemented everywhere it is used.

Comment: To be clear, my comments are directed to spender, not CVertex.

Comment: Yep. I suppose there is more to it than meets the eye!

Comment: I'm the maintainer of the PagedList library and I'd also like to point out that the 168k size is the source download - binaries download is 8k for the dll, pdb, and xml docs. The 168k source download also includes things like comprehensive XML documentation, unit tests, and Visual Studio project & solution files. The core implementation of the PagedList class itself is only 4.1k uncompiled, it is additions like StaticPagedList and some helpful extension methods that inflate the binary size.

Answer (score 4):

In Linq this would be

```
Users.Skip(pageSize*page).Take(pageSize)
```

This would assume zero based counting.

Answer (score 0):

[MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com) has a very flexible and easy to use pager